# Import date values in Sql Server with import packages

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2008

I have an annoying problem with importing data using Visual Studio in Sql Server. I created an SSIS import package with Visual Studio to import an Excel file (.xlsx). The sheet I import has a column populated with datetype values. Some values are left aligned, some are right aligned. If I format the entire column as datetype, I still get the two different types of alignment on that column: e.g. 4/1/2011 is right aligned, 13/01/2011 is left aligned.
I import the file with nvarchar for that column and I get NULL values for the left aligned values.
If I import the file with datetime datatype for that column, I get NULL values for the right aligned.

I don't care how the information "lands" in my Sql database, either as nvarchar or datetime, but I need the complete information, without the NULLS. This seems an Excel issue mostly, as the Excel does not see the values as being of the same datatypes, hence the different kinds of alignment. Any suggestions please? Grateful for any advice/suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems here. One, the right-aligned values are interpreted as dates but they are wrong because Excel thinks they are m/d/yyyy and you want d/m/yyyy. Two, the left-aligned values are interpreted as text.

Unfortunately, applying a format to the column when data is already there does not change the underlying storage. Since Excel already garbled the data you will need to parse out the correct values yourself.

Each problem above requires a different solution. Here's a visual showing how I broke down the problems and corresponding fixes:

[image]

Notice first the date formatting mentioned in `columns A, D, E, F`. This explains why the "fixed" version of 4/1/2011 looks the same as the source. In fact, the fixed version is January 4, whereas the source is April 1.

Here is the flow and formulae:

Columns B and C are helpers. They are desirable to simplify the fix in `column D`. The errors here don't matter; they will be ignored in the final step:

```
B3: =FIND("/",A3)
C3: =FIND("/",A3,B3+1)
```

Column D works on the data interpreted as text by parsing out where the numbers are amidst the slashes and building up a date value. You don't need this but I'm showing it for clarity:

```
D3: =DATE(RIGHT(A3,4),MID(A3,B3+1,C3-B3-1),LEFT(A3,B3-1))
```

Column E works on the data interpreted as date but where d and m are reversed. Again, not needed, but showing for clarity:

```
E3: =DATE(YEAR(A3),DAY(A3),MONTH(A3))
```

Column F pulls together D and E with an `IF` to apply the appropriate fix::

```
F3: =IF(ISERROR(VALUE(A3)),DATE(RIGHT(A3,4),MID(A3,B3+1,C3-B3-1),LEFT(A3,B3-1)),DATE(YEAR(A3),DAY(A3),MONTH(A3)))
```

Comment: Another option is to select column A and choose *Data|Text to Columns|Fixed Width|Next|Next|Date:DMY* Finish. Then format the number in DMY format. Destination can be set to another column if desired.